# I want to remove the add to cart button and the quantity widget

Tags: cart

I want to remove the add to cart button and the quantity widget, im using magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: from where you need to remove add to cart from list/ view??

Comment: Make the products out of stock.

Comment: Not so brilliant it does not show up in the list view..  thanks anyway...

Comment: Both list and view and I also need to remove quantity widget...

Comment: @Sebastien System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory  > Display Out of Stock Products

Answer (score 1):

To remove Add to cart button
From `Products list Page` goto

```
app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product
```

and open `list.phtml` file find for this code

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
<span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

and comment it.

to remove Quantity and Add to cart in Product View page open `view.phtml` in

```
app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product
```

find for this code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?> for removing add to cart
```

now for removing `quantity`

`app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view`

open `addtocart.phtml` find for this code

```
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <div class="qty-wrapper">
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Purchase Quantity:') ?></label>
            <input type="number" min="1" pattern="\d*" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="1000" value="<?php echo max($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1, 1) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />   </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

and comment it.Hope this helps.

Comment: In php how do you comment off a piece of code.  I tried // before the php tag but it does not work //<?php

Comment: `<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>` in this way [See Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp) and [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php).

Comment: @Sebastien if this solved your query accept the answer else ask me more for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It suggested to you checkout model which is disable cart and checkout feature from
 system.

Goto `admin>system>Configuration>Advance>Advance>`  find `Mage_Checkout`  change it value from  `Disable` and click Save config button for Disable he module.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i have update my answer